# Jest import common plugins like Vee Validate before each test

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm new to Jest and am testing my Nuxt JS application with unit testing. I have many test files set up and need to import various logic into each test file, such as my Vee Validate config.

I've tried adding it to a `setup.js` file and included this in `setupFilesAfterEnv` but it's not getting included.

What am I doing wrong?

**tests/unit/setup.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver, extend, configure, localize } from 'vee-validate'
import * as rules from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';
import en from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/en.json'

const config = {
  mode: 'lazy',
  classes: {
    valid: '',
    invalid: 'tw-border-red-500 dark:tw-border-white'
  }
}

Object.keys(rules).forEach(rule => {
  extend(rule, rules[rule]);
});

configure(config)

// Register it globally
Vue.component('ValidationObserver', ValidationObserver)
Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider)

// // activate the locales
localize({
  en
});
```

My `jest.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  silent: true,
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue', 'json'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest',
    'vee-validate/dist/rules': 'babel-jest'
  },
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/components/**/*.vue',
    '<rootDir>/pages/**/*.vue',
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!vee-validate/dist/rules)',
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '<rootDir>/tests/unit/setup.js'
  ]
}
```

And one of my test files called `LoanAmount` is:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises';
import LoanAmount from '@/components/Form/Steps/Loan/LoanAmount'

describe('LoanAmount', () => {
  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(LoanAmount)
    expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy()
  })

  test('amount is available for value', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(LoanAmount)
    await flushPromises()

    const amount = wrapper.findAll('.jest__amount-input')
    expect(amount.exists()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

If I include all of the contents from `tests/unit/setup.js` and include above my `describe` block then it works, but I can't be repeating this in each test file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setupFiles` property in `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    'vee-validate/dist/rules': 'babel-jest'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(vuetify)|(vue-material-design-icons)|(vee-validate/dist/rules)|(vue-picture-input/PictureInput.vue))'
  ],
  setupFiles: [
    './tests/unit/jest.setup.js'
  ],
  reporters: ['default', 'jest-junit'],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/**/Application/*.js'
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    '<rootDir>/vendor/',
    '<rootDir>/web/'
  ],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: process.env.COVERAGE_THRESHOLD_GLOBAL_BRANCH || 37,
      functions: process.env.COVERAGE_THRESHOLD_GLOBAL_FUNCTIONS || 40,
      lines: process.env.COVERAGE_THRESHOLD_GLOBAL_LINES || 50
    }
  }
}
```